# Application context path at JAX-RS 2.0 resource instance construction

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi, java-ee-7, contextpath

Is it possible to get the context path for a Java EE 7 application at JAX-RS 2.0 resource class instance construction time (and possibly at static class initialization time, too), or is it only available during requests to endpoints in the resource class?

By context path I mean the String that would be returned by a call to a `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()` within the Java EE 7 application.

I imagine that you probably could have multiple context path aliases for a deployed application.  If so, context path might be available only at request time.

I don't care, however, about the context path that was actually used in the URL for the request.  A canonical or default context path that will work for the endpoints in the class is good enough for me.

The technique to obtain such a context path need not be JAX-RS 2.0 specific.  It could come from some other Java EE 7 spec, as long as it works at JAX-RS 2.0 resource class construction time (or, more broadly, at static class initialization time).

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that the class is CDI `@ApplicationScoped`, so its constructor is not called at request time, as it would be if it were `@RequestScoped`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the base URI for your REST application by injecting `UriInfo` in a resource's constructor:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/resourcePath")
public class MyRestResource {

    public MyRestResource (@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        URI uri = uriInfo.getBaseUri();
    }

    @GET
    public Response someMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Most of the `UriInfo` methods will return `IllegalStateException` at resource construction time, but the `getBaseUri()` method will work.

It will return an URI like `http://<hostname>:<port>/<context-path>/<base-path>`.

But i'm not sure it would be possible to get it statically at class initialization time...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll try it out.  I actually saw that class earlier, but discounted it since its javadocs specify: "All methods throw java.lang.IllegalStateException if called outside the scope of a request" http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html

Comment: Also, I originally forgot to mention that the class is `@ApplicationScoped`, so the constructor is not called at request time.

Comment: Indeed, but javadoc specifies it again on each method except `getBaseUri()` and  `getBaseUriBuilder()`. I've tried on Wildfly 8.1 and it worked. The resource was `@ApplicationScoped` too.